# What is the $\int{w^a(1-w)^b\mathrm d w}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals, differential, elementary-functions

I recently came across the $$\int{w^a(1-w)^b\mathrm d w},$$ which looked ridiculously simple at first, but I subsequently discovered that I could not reduce it to some elementary form.

To clarify, I do *not* mean the following cases: when $a$ or $b$ is a nonnegative integer, for then integrating by parts does it; when $a$ and $b$ are negative integers, in theory one could do this since we only have a rational function, especially if $|a|$ and $|b|$ are not too large.

Thus, I mean that case when both $a$ and $b$ are *not* nonnegative integers. One might on impulse think that setting $a=b$ might simplify matters, but even in this restricted case I couldn't do anything -- integrating by parts is out of the question since it leads to an infinite series; changing the integrand in several ways doesn't do anything interesting; even differentiating with respect to $a=b$ only complicates the matter. I then began to wonder if it was possible at all.

So my question is this:

> Is it possible to reduce the above integral to elementary form? If so, what is a (theoretical) way to go about it? If not, why not? (I was originally interested in the case where $a\ne b,$ but the opposite case too should throw some light on the matter; in any case, progress will be appreciated.)

Comment: It's a hypergeometric function: $\dfrac{w^{a+1} \, _2F_1(a+1,-b;a+2;w)}{a+1}.$

Comment: This is a differential binomial. Check https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Differential_binomial

Comment: If $a=b,$ you get the beta function: $-\beta_{1-w}(a+1,a+1).$

Comment: @GReyes Your link was tantalising, but stopped short of satisfaction. It states that it cannot be reduced to elementary form and attributes this to Chebyshev, but doesn't cite any source for further reading. In any case, it seems it's an important form. Now that I know it has a name, I can easily make a search. Thanks.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Those aren't elementary functions.

Comment: @Allawonder: Yes, quite so. My point in typing up those results was to point out that I highly doubt there *is* an elementary function representation of those antiderivatives. There are many integrands that have no known elementary antiderivative, the most famous of course, is the Gaussian $e^{-x^2}.$

Comment: @AdrianKeister I see.

Comment: You can find the proof in the second volume of the complete works of Chebyshev, which is published both in French and in Russian (I happen to read both). No idea where else this could be found.

Comment: @GReyes Wow! I have only very elementary knowledge of those languages.

Comment: if $a=b=-1/2$, there exists a primitive https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2FSqrt%5Bx%281-x%29%5D&lang=fr